# Date format Moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using format like this works in moment.js

```
function test {
    return "DD-MM-YY"
}
```

but changing to `"DD-MM-YY"` doesn't work anymore.
Does anyone know why?

I'm trying to compare 2 dates:

```
function test {
    return "DD-MM-YY"
}

var monthMoment = moment().add(1, 'months');

var currentVal = moment($('#fromtextbox').val(), test(), true);
    if (currentVal.isAfter(monthMoment)) {
        return curentVal;
    }
    return monthMoment;
```

Comment: can you please share some code as so far?

Comment: Show us what you are trying.

Comment: it certainly works for me

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do you mean like this? I test it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `format`:

```
var monthMoment = moment().add(1, 'months').format("DD-MM-YYYY");
var currentVal= moment($('#fromtextbox').val(), test(), true).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```